# Почему при прыжке в 2д платформере персонаж будто бы телепортируется, а не плавно летит вверх?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Понятия не имею, что здесь может быть не так:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

onready var ANIM = get_node("AnimatedSprite")

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    var vel = Vector2()
    
    var GRAV = 6000 * delta
    var JUMP = 4000
    var SPEED = 120
    var FLOOR = Vector2.UP
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        vel.x -= SPEED
        ANIM.play("run") 
        ANIM.flip_h = false
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        vel.x += SPEED
        ANIM.play("run")
        ANIM.flip_h = true
    else:
        vel.x = 0
        ANIM.play("stay")
    
    if not is_on_floor():
        ANIM.play("fly")
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("up") and is_on_floor():
        vel.y -= JUMP
        
    vel.y += GRAV
    
    move_and_slide(vel, FLOOR)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Требуется в `vel.y -= JUMP` добавить `* delta`

```
vel.y -= JUMP * delta
```